# Tab bar controller push segue instead (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I don't really know how to explain this but i have a tab bar controller and a qr code scanner controller, how can i make it perform a segue to the qr code scanner (exactly like the Instagram camera, when u tap on the camera icon, the whole tab bar disappears and segue to the camera page) instead of just tapping it. Thank you in advance for reading this.

[Image of Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvxuH.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't link QR scanner controller into tabbar.
2. Link some empty VC to 3-d tab
3. Setup delegate for your tabbar controller
4. implement method:

   ```
   public func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
       if tabBarController.viewControllers!.last == viewController {
           // present your vc
           return false
       }
       return true
   }
   ```